# Reorder default pip3 Mac

Tags: python, macos, unix, pip

I've recently updated and cleaned up my python environment on Mac, but can't seem to get my pip3 to point to the correct installation.

I'd like to have pip point to /usr/local/bin/pip3, but its still pointing to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/pip3.

```
% which -a pip3                                                          1.059s
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
/Users/bavtuning/Library/Python/3.8/bin/pip3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That's your PATH.  You can rearrange that in your shell rc file.  Or, create symbolic links in ~/bin, which is usually first in the PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Thank Tim!  Rearranged my zhrc file and all is good.